# No records returned when at least one record exists that doesn't meet condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

Firstly I know this query is a bit of a mess but it works fine until at least 1 `ticket` record exists with `cancelled` set to true at which point no records are returned. If there is another record with `cancelled` set to false or a combination of both then it works fine ie. records returned with all the ticket totals either set to 0 or the appropriate value.

I've updated the query to have `where... t.cancelled = 0 or t.cancelled IS NULL` and also changed the ticket table join to left (tried full outer also) but it still suffers from the problem above.

Why is this happening and what can I do to prevent it?

```
select Title, PerformanceStarts, sum(sold) as sold, sum(sold * value) as revenue, idperformance, DoorsOpening, onsale, active, showactive, venueid,
    (
        select sum(Quantity) from allocations
        where IdAllocation in (select allocationid from PerformancePriceBands where PerformanceID = idperformance) and OnGeneralSale = 1) as alloc, 
            (
                select count(totaltickets) from
                    ( 
                        select count(t.idticket) as totaltickets from tickets t
                        where t.PerformancePriceBandID IN
                            (
                                select idperformancepriceband from PerformancePriceBands
                                where performanceid = IdPerformance) and (t.Cancelled = 0 or t.Cancelled IS NULL)
                                group by t.BookingID
                            ) as q
                where totaltickets > 7
            ) as largegroups,
            (
                select count(totaltickets) from
                    ( 
                        select count(t.idticket) as totaltickets from tickets t
                        where t.PerformancePriceBandID IN
                            (
                                select idperformancepriceband from PerformancePriceBands
                                where performanceid = IdPerformance) and (t.Cancelled = 0 or t.Cancelled IS NULL)
                                group by t.BookingID
                            ) as q
                where totaltickets between 5 and 7
            ) as mediumgroups
    from
        (
            select p.idperformance, s.title, p.PerformanceStarts, count(t.idticket) as sold, ppb.Value, p.DoorsOpening, p.OnSale, p.Active, s.active as showactive, p.VenueID
            from shows s
            join performances p on p.ShowID = s.IdShow
            join PerformancePriceBands ppb on ppb.PerformanceID = p.IdPerformance
            left join tickets t on t.PerformancePriceBandID = ppb.IdPerformancePriceBand
            where p.IdPerformance = 23206 and (t.Cancelled = 0 or t.Cancelled is null)
            group by s.title, p.performancestarts, ppb.Value, p.idperformance, p.DoorsOpening, p.onsale, p.active, s.active, p.VenueID
        ) as q
group by title, PerformanceStarts, IdPerformance, DoorsOpening, onsale, Active, showactive, VenueID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the Cancelled criteria to the join condition.

```
left join tickets t on t.PerformancePriceBandID = ppb.IdPerformancePriceBand and t.Cancelled = 0
```

and remove it from the where clause.

Comment: Perfect! Out of curiosity why does it work when specified in the join and not in the where clause?

Comment: When specified in the join, the condition is applied to the right-side dataset only and before it gets joined to the left-side. When it's in the where clause, it gets applied to the dataset that results from the join.